# How to make image echo line up with next image in table rows

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-table

I'm having an issue making my images line up properly from my mySQL database. The issue I'm having is, I essentially want to load 24 images on this page from a CMS. I have the images loading into a table which is designed to have 4 images per line. The issue: The first line has 2 images, the second has 1 image, the third has 3 images, the fourth has 1 image, the fifth has 3 images, and the sixth and seventh have 1 image per row.  I cannot get 4 images per row. Can anyone help  out?

```
<!-- IMAGE GALLERY -->

    <h2 class="text1">Image Gallery</h2>
    <p>Click any image to open up a larger version</p>
    <div class="gallery">
        <?php
            $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM cmhimage ORDER BY id DESC";
            $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            ?><table><?php 
            $level = 1;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
                $description = $row['capt'];
                $photo = $row['file'];
                $count = 1;
                $level = $level + $count;

                if (($level == 4) || ($level == 8) || ($level == 12) || ($level == 16) || ($level == 20) || ($level == 24)){
                    echo '<tr>';
                }

                 // Display the data
                echo '<td><table><tr><td><a href="manage/image/' . $photo . '" target="_blank"><img class="imgcontain" src="manage/image/' . $photo .'" border="0"/></a></td></tr></td><br/>';  
                echo '<td><tr><td><p class="caption">' . $description .'</p></tr></td></table></td>';  
                if (($level == 4) || ($level == 8) || ($level == 12) || ($level == 16) || ($level == 20) || ($level == 24)){
                    echo '</tr>';   
                    }

            }
            mysqli_close($dbc);

        ?>
       </table>
```

Here is the CSS if this is the issue.

```
.gallery {
width: 525px;
}
.imgcontain {
padding-right:15px; 
float: left;
width: 110px;
height: 110px
}
.caption {
font:bold 78% arial,helvetica,sans-serif; 
text-align:center; 
position: relative;
right: 10px;
color:#056063;
}
```

Comment: Instead of that long `if` statement, try `$level % 4 > 0`.

Comment: That changed it to a format now of 
Row 1 has 1 image, R2 has 2, R3 and R4 have 1, R5 has 2 and so on

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how the images are being displayed?

Comment: Your problem is not related to mysql but to css and the distribution of the images. Also your html markup seems very complex with nested tables and a `<br/>` separating two `<td>`s. Try simplifying this.

Comment: You initialize `$level` as 1, but you increment it immediately within the loop.  The very first image ends up being 2 according to your level counter.  Also, there's no reason to set `$count` as a variable unless you're actually going to use it as a variable (try a constant or just hardcode the 1 in your addition statement).

Answer (score 0):

there are many issues.
first the code is barely readable

with this construction the first tr are not display
instead of

```
 if (($level == 4) || ($level == 8) || ($level == 12) || ($level == 16) || ($level == 20) || ($level == 24))
```

try

```
if($level == 1 || $level % 4 == 0)
```

and instaed of

```
echo '<td><table><tr><td><a href="manage/image/' . $photo . '" target="_blank"><img class="imgcontain" src="manage/image/' . $photo .'" border="0"/></a></td></tr></td><br/>';
echo '<td><tr><td><p class="caption">' . $description .'</p></tr></td></table></td>';
```

try this

```
echo '<td>';
echo ' <table>';
echo '  <tr>';
echo '    <td>';
echo '       <a href="manage/image/' . $photo . '" target="_blank"><img class="imgcontain" src="manage/image/' . $photo .'" border="0"/></a>';
echo '   </td>';
echo '   <td>';
echo '     <p class="caption">' . $description .'</p>';
echo '   </td>';
echo '  </tr>';
echo ' </table>';
echo '</td>';
```

and

```
if (($level == 4) || ($level == 8) || ($level == 12) || ($level == 16) || ($level == 20) || ($level == 24)){
                    echo '</tr>';   
                    }
```

like the first one.

try format your code. with this spaces you would have seen that many cells and rows were not closed.

edit:
put 
    $count = 1
before the while starts!
and in the last line of the while this:

```
$count++;
```

Comment: The `$count` variable is never incremented, `$level` is.

Comment: nope, $level will stuck at 2, because in each iteration he adds 1+1
($level=1, $count=1) and both are currently not inkremented.

Comment: No, look at it again.  `$level` is initialized outside of the loop at 1.  Inside the loop `$count` is set to 1, then `$level = $level + $count` immediately follows.  There is never a time where `$count` is incremented or even looked at beyond the addition to `$level`, it is only ever set to 1 with each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<h2 class="text1">Image Gallery</h2>
<p>Click any image to open up a larger version</p>
<div class="gallery">
    <?php
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cmhimage ORDER BY id DESC";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        ?>
    <table><tr>
        <?php 
        $level = 1;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
            $description = $row['capt'];
            $photo = $row['file'];
            $count = 4; //items per row

            if (($level > $count) && $level%$count==1){
                echo '
        </tr>
        <tr>';
            }

             // Display the data
//part of code from mercsen
echo '<td>';
echo ' <table>';
echo '  <tr>';
echo '    <td>';
echo '       <a href="manage/image/' . $photo . '" target="_blank"><img class="imgcontain" src="manage/image/' . $photo .'" border="0"/></a>';
echo '   </td>';
echo '   <td>';
echo '     <p class="caption">' . $description .'</p>';
echo '   </td>';
echo '  </tr>';
echo ' </table>';
echo '</td>';
            $level++;
        }
        mysqli_close($dbc);

    ?>
       </tr>
   </table>
```